# Why is delete called edit on iOS, and why is it hold to delete for an app?

Tags: ios

One of the most confusing things I find out iOS is the concept of the "edit" button turning on some special "delete" mode in apps, this seems like the standard from the UI guidelines. Why doesn't iOS apply this same use pattern when uninstalling an app from the device, instead for an app uninstall it is "hold to delete." What is the reasoning behind these two different patterns that accomplish the same thing, but aren't applied consistently? More importantly, what is the proper way to implement the delete UI pattern on an iOS app?

Comment: there is no edit button on home screen so it does not apply

Comment: Why wouldn't they just apply the hold to delete pattern everywhere then?

Comment: Well, maybe pressing and holding seems like a good paradigm for a grid of icons, whereas it's more natural to just swipe a table view row off the screen... What do you think of that?

Comment: Both of those make sense to me, what about this edit to delete mode thing?

Comment: "hold to do something" is kind of "hidden gesture" which need user to learn first. whereas press "edit" button to delete is very natural.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an straight answer.

But I can see why Apple would choose such a gesture, and the reason is two-fold. First, the **screen space is valuable**, and second, one needs to be accessed more **frequently** than the other.

## Space is Valuable

Let's pretend that the application launcher (aka. springboard) were to support the same edit functionality, where do you fit all the new interface?

Following standard UI principles would indicate that having a big fat bar on the top of the screen with an "Edit" button that would display the "(x)", but that top bar would provide... nothing actually, it would just be a placeholder for the Edit button. An entire 320 x 44 pt^2 wasted on a single button, even worse in iPad.

Let's try the opposite, apply the "Hold to delete" pattern on the items of a tableview within an App. We would need to press and hold a cell, then it would show the remove item, but also display the rearrange marker (the three-lines thingy). The content would get so padded that the text that read "This is an item", would probably be shrinked to "This i...". Space becomes an issue again.

Having the edit button is affordable inside an app, because you probably already have a navigation bar on top, or a toolbar on the bottom. Whereas the springboard needs all the space possible to show as many apps as possible.

## Frequency of use

Whenever you design an interface, you gotta ask yourself this questions "How frequently will they use this feature?" If the answer is "All the goddamn time", then it needs to be put on the top of any list, forefront of the application, or wherever it stands out.

- Deleting or Archiving emails? I do that all the time, usually selecting multiple of them.
- Deleting applications? I usually don't even install them in the first place.

Notice that the delete/edit also gets a swipe gesture that takes milliseconds to accomplish, whereas, deleting applications requires a long timed gesture.

True, it doesn't always work for everyone, we all know someone who is madly installing and deleting applications to try them all out, but they are not the norm.

Pay attention to what applications have the edit button at hand, and you can see the assumptions made by Apple about how much is that button needed.

To **answer your other question**, it all depends on how frequently do you expect your users to delete the content you're providing, and how much you value space.

If, for instance, you don't have a top navigation bar and deleting will be rarely used, put it in a swipe-only gesture (e.g. ). If deleting should be done frequently, edit button is recommended (e.g. shopping list). If deleting is quintessential for the function of your app (e.g. Reminders) then the you should consider having something like the checkmarks on Reminders.

Also, you can cheat the system, and have an edit button on the navigation bar, but hide the navigation bar as you scroll downwards. Apple did something similar on the iOS 7 (seen at WWDC) with safari.

In truth, the iOS app guidelines don't tell you everything, they offer recommendations, but the liberty is yours to explore new interactions, and that's why I love iOS and the vast amount of new things that come out from it. The "pull to refresh" on the Twiiter app was copied pretty much everywhere (even apple uses it now on the mails app) (and twitter holds a patent of it, btw).